# Gulp watch not triggering minify on file change

Tags: gulp

I have simple starter app, I created gulpfile.js file with content below,

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
// Task to minify css using package cleanCSs
gulp.task('minify-css', () => {
     // Folder with files to minify
     return gulp.src('src/assets/styles/*.css')
     //The method pipe() allow you to chain multiple tasks together 
     //I execute the task to minify the files
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    //I define the destination of the minified files with the method dest
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/assets/dist'));
});

//We create a 'default' task that will run when we run `gulp` in the project
gulp.task('default', function() {
// We use `gulp.watch` for Gulp to expect changes in the files to run again
  gulp.watch('./src/assets/styles/*.css', function(evt) {
    gulp.task('minify-css');
  });
});
```

if I run `gulp minify-css` it works expected, but I need it to minify on file change

But all its do log a message in cmd windows like 'Starting ...'

I don't even know what does it mean...

package.json:

```
..
     "gulp": "^4.0.2",
     "gulp-clean-css": "^4.2.0"
```

Comment: `return gulp.src('src/assets/styles/*.css')` did you mean `return gulp.src('./src/assets/styles/*.css')` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add return when running task minify-css, so that system knows when previous task was completed.

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
// We use `gulp.watch` for Gulp to expect changes in the files to run again
  gulp.watch('./src/assets/styles/*.css', function(evt) {
    return gulp.task('minify-css');
  });
});
```